# How to remove link image with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have one textarea and I want to past the image link into text area then click submit to remove link from image.

This is what I have tried -

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['ids'])) {
    $array = explode("<a href=", $_GET['ids']);
print_r($array[0]); // piece1
print_r($array[1]);
print_r($array[2]);
print_r($array[3]);
print_r($array[4]);

}

?>

<form method="get" action="">
    <textarea style="width:50%; height:400px;" name="ids"></textarea><br />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This link will past in text area

```
<a href="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-6W0AHlmD4Bo/WcjgQ5CK2nI/AAAAAAAADw0/OUYgbTg8CJM2saIrbkARgqBmn0aviDiWACLcBGAs/s1600/CIMG3395.jpg" imageanchor="1" ><img border="0" src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-6W0AHlmD4Bo/WcjgQ5CK2nI/AAAAAAAADw0/OUYgbTg8CJM2saIrbkARgqBmn0aviDiWACLcBGAs/s1600/CIMG3395.jpg" data-original-width="1024" data-original-height="768" /></a>
```

And result I want after clicking submit button display html code below , please help me I don't know how to start writing code.

```
<img border="0" src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-6W0AHlmD4Bo/WcjgQ5CK2nI/AAAAAAAADw0/OUYgbTg8CJM2saIrbkARgqBmn0aviDiWACLcBGAs/s1600/CIMG3395.jpg" data-original-width="1024" data-original-height="768" />
```

This is what I have tried:

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['ids'])) { 
  $array = explode("<a href=", $_GET['ids']); 
  print_r($array[0]);  
  //piece1 
  print_r($array[1]); 
  print_r($array[2]);
  print_r($array[3]);
  print_r($array[4]); } 
?>
  <form method="get" action="">
    <textarea style="width:50%; height:400px;" name="ids"></textarea>
    <br />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: please clarify what your problem is, show us what you have tried and if you have any errors show the error.

Comment: This Is what i have tried

`<?php if (isset($_GET['ids'])) {
 $array = explode("<a href=", $_GET['ids']);
print_r($array[0]); // piece1
print_r($array[1]);
print_r($array[2]);
print_r($array[3]);
print_r($array[4]);
 
}

?>

<form method="get" action="">
    <textarea style="width:50%; height:400px;" name="ids"></textarea><br />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>`

Answer (score 1):

first you should add img to a variable andd then remove link, and add the variable to the container of the link for example:

```js
     $("#b").click(function(){
      var img = $("#link_img");
      
      $("#link").remove();
      $("#container").html(img);
      
     })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <a id="link" href="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-6W0AHlmD4Bo/WcjgQ5CK2nI/AAAAAAAADw0/OUYgbTg8CJM2saIrbkARgqBmn0aviDiWACLcBGAs/s1600/CIMG3395.jpg" imageanchor="1" ><img border="0" id="link_img"  src="a.jpg" data-original-width="1024" data-original-height="768" /></a>
    
     </div>
    <button id="b">submit</button>
    
    <script>

    </script>
```

Comment: That's neat, to improve your answer, you could copy/paste it in a snippet (Ctrl-M) and select a jQuery version to handle the `$('...')` stuff. Then we can run it and watch the link disappear as we click on submit !

Answer (score 0):

Its simple remove 'a' tag

```
<img border="0" src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-6W0AHlmD4Bo/WcjgQ5CK2nI/AAAAAAAADw0/OUYgbTg8CJM2saIrbkARgqBmn0aviDiWACLcBGAs/s1600/CIMG3395.jpg" data-original-width="1024" data-original-height="768" />

<form action="/action_page.xxx" onsubmit="myFunction()">
  Enter name: <input type="text" name="fname">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    alert("The form was submitted");
}
</script>
```

Removing tag:

```
<script>
var atagid = <?php echo $_GET['ids'];?>;
function myFunction() {
        alert("The form was submitted");
       $("atagid").removeAttr("href");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I think that he wants to know how to remove the 'a' tag when you click on the submit button

Comment: This Is what i have tried

`<?php if (isset($_GET['ids'])) {
 $array = explode("<a href=", $_GET['ids']);
print_r($array[0]); // piece1
print_r($array[1]);
print_r($array[2]);
print_r($array[3]);
print_r($array[4]);
 
}

?>

<form method="get" action="">
    <textarea style="width:50%; height:400px;" name="ids"></textarea><br />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>`

Comment: use this <script>
function myFunction() {
        alert("The form was submitted");
var atagid = <?php echo $_GET['ids'];?>;
       $("atagid").removeAttr("href");
    }
</script>